# Google Reader Subscriptions With OAuth2

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, google-oauth

I'm trying to get my subscription list through OAuth2 from Google Reader.
I'm using Codeigniter and a [library - CI_OPAUTH](https://github.com/destinomultimedia/ci_opauth). I can get the permissions scren with no problems and give Google Reader permissions. The problem is when i get the callback header after authentication is done it give me an 403 Forbidden header.

Here are my options for the library:

```
    $config['opauth_config'] = array(
    'path' => '/mixordia/index.php/oauth/login/', //example: /ci_opauth/auth/login/
    'callback_url' => '/mixordia/index.php/oauth/authenticate/', //example: /ci_opauth/auth/authenticate/
    'callback_transport' => 'get', //Codeigniter don't use native session
    'security_salt' => 'mixordias_salt_whwhwh_wayacross',
    'debug' => true,
    'Strategy' => array(
        'Google' => array(
            'client_id' => 'MY_ID',
            'client_secret' => 'MY_SECRET',
            'service' => 'reader',
            'source' => 'APP Name',
            'scope' => 'http://www.google.com/reader/api'
        )
    )
);
```

Here is what i get:

```
Array
(
[error] => Array
    (
        [provider] => Google
        [code] => userinfo_error
        [message] => Failed when attempting to query for user information
        [raw] => Array
            (
                [response] => 0
                [headers] => HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest",     error=insufficient_scope, scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.id h ttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthLogin"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 12:26:25 GMT
Expires: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 12:26:25 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
            )

    )

[timestamp] => 2013-06-13T12:26:25+00:00
)
```

I've stuck in this for 2 days and I don't know what I'm doing wrong in the request with the library. can you help me?

Comment: On the off chance that you are not aware. Google Reader is going away very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library tries to [get user's profile](https://github.com/destinomultimedia/ci_opauth/blob/d31a0e6e147344f298165b02cde8a8eb5fc239db/application/libraries/Opauth/Strategy/Google/GoogleStrategy.php#L134), which requires userinfo.profile scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile). Add that scope to your config and it should work.